# My javascript is adding html elements in the wrong direction

Tags: javascript, html, css

You Can view the website at this link:  https://ogdens-flooring-estimator.hunterscott1.repl.co/

So if you press the tile radio then click the next button That will get you to the page with the problem.

press the +option button it wild add a new form, as well as add new information into the estimate, but in the estimate it adds it on the same line. Any fix on how to make it stack vertically instead of horizontally.

Sorry if my code is a bit messy. feel free to ask for any clarification. Most of the code affecting this process lies on lines 160-201 But there is some more code that effects it on lines 38-53. Just to clarify this is on the Tile.js file, the problem could also be in the Tile.html or Tile.css but I doubt it.

This link will lead you to a copy of the code: https://repl.it/@HunterScott2/Ogdens-Flooring-Estimator

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your option tag is a html predefined tag including predefined css. Just rename it to fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use display: flex, see example

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #EBF3FE;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three
    <br>has
    <br>extra
    <br>text
  </div>
</div>
```